# C# Using wyBuild for updating

Tags: c#, wybuild

Is there a way to automate the process of checking updates?
I would like my application to automatically check updates when it starts, instead of having to click on a MenuStrip.

Comment: Are you handling the update when the user selects the MenuStrip Item?

Comment: Yeah.
There is no other way I could find...

Comment: Then you can just move that same code into you constructor when you form loads, then the update will be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

AutomaticUpdater control has one property which is called `DaysBetweenChecks`
Set no of days to check automatically.